# .hover doesn't work anymore when .click inserted

Tags: jquery, html, css, click, hover

First, please take a look at my jQuery.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".pic").find('img').hover(
    function(){ // hover in
        $(this).animate({width: "450", height: "300"}, 200);
    }, 
    function(){ // hover out
        $(this).animate({width: "150", height: "100"}, 1000); 
    });

    $(".zoom").click(function(){     // click for the lightbox
        var go = $(this).find('img').attr("src");   // get clicked link href
        $("#box").html('<img src="'+go+'"/>');  // place href as img src value

        $('#backdrop, #box').animate({opacity: ".6"}, 500, 'linear');
        $('#box').find('img').animate({opacity:
        $('#box').animate({opacity: '1'}, 300, 'linear');
        $('#backdrop, #box').css('display', 'block');
    });

    $("#backdrop").click(function(){     // close the lightbox
        $("#backdrop, #box").animate({opacity: "0"}, 500, "linear", function(){
            $("#backdrop, #box").hide();
        });
    });
});
```

So this is what I've done,
my `.hover` function works fine when there is no `.click` function written below
but it becomes functionless when I put `.click` function below.

Comment: By the way, it refers <div class="pic"><a href="#" class="zoom">

Answer (score 2):

There is a syntax bug in your code:

```
$('#box').find('img').animate({opacity:
```

This could be preventing your code form working.  When I comment out this line (and make up some HTML that works with your selectors, then the hover and click events work, they are independent events so you can bind them to the same element.)

JavaScript is evaluated all at once inside a script tag or a .js file before it is executed, so even though your hover script it correct a syntax error in your click script is preventing the rest of your JavaScript from being executed.  if these two blocks of code had been in separate script elements (or separate .js files) then the hover would work while the click would fail.  This of course is not the solution, you need to fix your unclosed object literal.  Install Firebug in Firefox or enable the Developer tools in IE to see this error.  It can be hard to debug without tools like this.

Comment: The answer? Add two forward slashes to comment out. Seriously though, this is an error in the code and could be the reason.

Comment: I suggested that they comment out the line but only user2129377 knows that opacity the animated element was supposed to have

Comment: Why not just tell the user to add the closing `)};` around the statement

Comment: @CodyGuldner, that is what "you need to fix your unclosed object literal." means.  I didn't elaborate because it appears from the rest of the code that user2129377 knows that.  Also, small point, but they should add '});'.

Comment: Actually that correction of your correction is wrong. What they need to do is add a value (float or int) followed by a } closing the object literal, and then followed by ); closing the function parameters (technically the semicolon is optional but really good practice)